# How to start a broadcast receiver on a separate global process from that of the application?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-broadcastreceiver

I have an android application where I am implementing push notifications using GCM. I have a broadcast receiver and an intent service for handling GCM Push notifications. My requirement is that I want to receive the notification inside OnReceive of the broadcast receiver in such a way that the Application doesn't get created before that. 
According to Android Developer docs :

Called when the application is starting, before any activity, 
service, or **receiver** objects have been created. Note that content 
providers are created before the application object.

I have tried to start the broadcast receiver in a separate Global Process from that of the application, but on doing this the GCMBroadcastReceiver doesn't get triggered at all on sending a notification.
Is this possible at all, if yes how?

Answer (score 3):

> I want to receive the notification inside OnReceive of the broadcast receiver in such a way that the Application doesn't get created before that

That is not possible, sorry.